# django object won't save

Tags: django, object, django-views

When I try to create a new object using the code in my view, the object is not created. No errors are thrown, it simply reloads the page, but when I try and view the database, no objects exist in the liquororder table. The code used to work, and a similar code works in another place I used it, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work here. Let me know if you might need any other code.

model:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    OrderID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    storeID = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    DateCreated = models.DateField('Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
    OrderName = models.CharField('Order Name', max_length=25 )
    Active = models.BooleanField()

class LiquorOrder(models.Model):
    pack_size = (
                ('7', '7'),
                ('7', '7'),
            )

    LiquorOrderID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    storeliquorID = models.ForeignKey(StoreLiquor)
    orderID = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    OrderAmount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Order Amount', max_length=3, choices=pack_size)
    TotalPrice = models.DecimalField('Total Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Form:

```
class AddToOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LiquorOrder
        fields = ('OrderAmount',)
```

view:

```
def storeliquor(request, store_id, liquor_id):

    a = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_id)
    storeliquor = StoreLiquor.objects.get(liquorID=liquor_id)
    s = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
    x = Order.objects.get(storeID=s, Active=True)
    y = a.OffPremisePrice
    c = a.BottleSize


    g = request.POST.get('OrderAmount', '')
    b = a.PackSize
    h = b*2
    d = b*3
    e = b*4
    r = b*5
    if c == "1750 ML":
        pack_size = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('3', '3'),
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (d, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )
    elif c == "1000 ML":
        pack_size = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('6', '6'),
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (d, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )
    elif c == "750 ML":
        pack_size = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('6', '6'),
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (c, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )
    elif c == "375 ML":
        pack_size = (
            ('3', '3'),
            ('6', '6'),
            ('12', '12'),
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (d, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )
    elif c == "200 ML":
        pack_size = (
            ('12', '12'),
            ('24', '24'),
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (d, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )
    else:
        pack_size = (
            (b, b),
            (h, h),
            (d, d),
            (e, e),
            (r, r),
        )

    if request.method == "POST":
        f = AddToOrderForm(request.POST)
        updateform = AddLiquorForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            z = f.save(commit=False)
            z.TotalPrice = (float(y)) * (float(g))
            z.storeliquorID = a
            z.orderID = x
            z.OrderAmount = g
            z.save()

        if updateform.is_valid():
            liquor = StoreLiquor.objects.get(liquorID=liquor_id)
            liquor.StorePrice = request.POST.get('StorePrice', '')
            liquor.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/stores/get/%s' % store_id)

    else:
        f = AddToOrderForm()
        f.fields['OrderAmount'].choices = pack_size

        updateform = AddLiquorForm(
         initial={'StorePrice': storeliquor.StorePrice }
        )
    args = {}


    args['liquor'] = a
    args['s'] = s
    args['form'] = f
    args['form2'] = updateform

    return render(request,'storeliquor.html', args)
```

The form as it appears in the HTML:

```
<form action="/stores/storeliquors/{{ s.StoreID }}/{{ liquor.id }}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_p}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Order">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you will never see any errors, since you always redirect, regardless of form being valid or not.

You should add indentation to this line:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/stores/get/%s' % store_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You always redirect on post, even if one or both of the forms are invalid. You should only redirect if both are valid - in fact you should not even save either of them unless both are valid.

And please, please use some proper descriptive variable names. This isn't 1978, and you're not running in 16k of memory.